# Visual Studio - window layout according to open file type

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, layout, window

In Visual Studio, is possible to set window layout according to open (just viewed) file type?

For example, when I design a graphical user interface, thus I edit some *xaml* file, I would like *Properties Window* to be shown, but when I edit any other file, for example some *cs* file, I do not use that Properties Window, so I do not want the Properties Window to be displayed at that moment.

In other words, can window layout in Visual Studio be "file type specific"?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way that I'm aware of to change the window layout automatically based on what type of file is currently open/being edited.

It's not automatic, but, if you haven't already, you may try [Layouts O Rama](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/35966ad9-430f-4ad7-9186-4394b784e36c) or [Perspectives](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d446d9d3-4994-4d78-853d-f266b0bfd4ec).  I had some problems with Perspectives (kept losing my saved window layouts) but Layouts O Rama has worked quite well for me.  You can set the layouts to a keyboard shortcut so, while again, it's not automatic, you can map (for example) Tools.LoadWindowsLayout1 to your layout that shows the properties window and Tool.LoadWindowsLayout2 to your layout that hides it, and then simply switch between them by hitting your shortcut key.